# PyTorch: How to create sample weights matrix from a tensor of number of frames

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

this has probably been answered before but I could not come up with the appropriate search query to find the previous answers so apologies if you've answered this before.

Let's say I have a batch size of 4 and a 1D tensor specifying the "unpadded" lengths of my input features `input_lengths=[4, 6, 8, 10]`.

My feature tensor will be of shape `(4, 10, C)` for C dimensional features at each timestep. I want to create a sample weights matrix of shape `(4, 10)` which is for each datum in the batch, filled with ones up to the "unpadded" length of that datum. So, for the case above,

```
sample_weights = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I don't want to have a for-loop and was wondering if there's a more efficient way of creating this `sample_weights` matrix using `torch.Tensor` functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a benchmark between both approaches.

```
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence

def build_w_vec(inputs):
    rows = len(inputs)
    cols = sorted(inputs)[-1]
    w = torch.zeros(rows, cols)
    # start and end steps are incremented by `1` to avoid null indexing when filling `w`
    aranges_list = list(map(lambda l: torch.arange(start=1, end=l + 1), inputs))
    aranges_tensor = pad_sequence(aranges_list, batch_first=True)
    w[aranges_tensor != 0] = 1
    return w


def build_w_iter(inputs):
    rows = len(inputs)
    cols = sorted(inputs)[-1]
    w = torch.zeros(rows, cols)
    for i, length in enumerate(inputs):
        arange = torch.arange(length)
        w[i, arange] = 1
    return w
```

[image]